# sendmail "unknown user", mail forward task

Tags: sendmail, ubuntu-16.04

I have an ubuntu 16.04 web server with a forwarded mx record. On server, I installed sendmail.
I have multiple vhosts runnning. One of them is "xxx-tele.com".

Now I want to setup sendmail that all mails sent to info@xxx-tele.com should be forwarded to xxx@tele.com which is a mailbox on a different mail server inside of my network.

First I added a /etc/mail/virtusertable with

```
info@xxx-tele.com        xxx@tele.com
```

and with "makemap hash virtusertable.db <  virtusertable" I created the hash file.
In /etc/mail/sendmail.mc I added the line

```
FEATURE(`virtusertable', `hash -o /etc/mail/virtusertable.db')dnl
```

and I run the

```
m4 /etc/mail/sendmail.mc > /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
```

command and restarted sendmail with "service sendmail reload".

Now, I try command

```
sendmail -bv info@xxx-tele.com
```

and I just get response:
info@xxx-tele.com... User unknown

The xxx-tele.com is appended in /etc/hosts and in /etc/mail/local-host-names

How can I setup sendmail to just forward this address and refuse all other?

The command: echo '$=w' | sendmail -bt just returns:

```
ADDRESS TEST MODE (ruleset 3 NOT automatically invoked) 
Enter <ruleset> <address> 
> localhost.tele.com
web
xxx-tele.com
[internal.dmz.ip4.address]
localhost
web.tele.com
[127.0.0.1]
web.tele.com
[localhost.tele.com]
```

Best,
dwi

here are the provided information:
The answer for 1.) is

```
ADDRESS TEST MODE (ruleset 3 NOT automatically invoked) 
Enter <ruleset> <address>
 > map_lookup: virtuser (info@xxx-tele.com) returns myuser@tele.com (0)
```

The answer for 2.) is

```
ADDRESS TEST MODE (ruleset 3 NOT automatically invoked)
Enter <ruleset> <address>
> canonify input: info @ xxx-tele.com
Canonify2 input: info < @ xxx-tele.com >
map_lookup(host, xxx-tele.com, %0=xxx-tele.com) => localhost.xxx.com. (0)
Canonify2 returns: info < @ localhost.xxx.com . >
canonify returns: info < @ localhost.xxx.com . >
parse input: info < @ localhost.xxx.com . >
Parse0 input: info < @ localhost.xxx. com . >
map_lookup(dequote, info, %0=info) => NOT FOUND (0)
Parse0 returns: info < @ localhost.xxx.com . >
Parse1 input: info < @ localhost. xxx.com . >
map_lookup(virtuser, info@localhost.xxx.com, %0=info@localhost.xxx.com, %1=info) => NOT FOUND (0)
map_lookup(virtuser, @localhost.xxx.com, %0=@localhost.xxx.com, %1=info) => NOT FOUND (0)
Parse1 returns: $# local $: info
parse returns: $# local $: info
```

The third response is:

```
> root@web:~# _res.options = 812c3, HasWildcardMX = 0
Enter <ruleset> <address>
> canonify           input: info @ xxx-tele . com
Canonify2          input: info < @ xxx-tele . com >
Canonify2        returns: info < @ localhost . xxx. com . >
canonify         returns: info < @ localhost . xxx. com . >
parse              input: info < @ localhost . xxx. com . >
Parse0             input: info < @ localhost . xxx. com . >
Parse0           returns: info < @ localhost . xxx. com . >
Parse1             input: info < @ localhost . xxx. com . >
Parse1           returns: $# local $: info
parse            returns: $# local $: info
```

My host file is like:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost    localhost.xxx.com    xxx-tele.com
local.dmz.ip4.address      web.xxx.com     web    xxx-tele.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domain gets rewritten by host map lookup before virtusertable lookup
as indicated by debug output provided by

```
echo '3,0 info@xxx-tele.com' | sendmail -d60.5 -bt
```

Changing your /etc/hosts entry should fix it

```
### Old Entry
# 127.0.0.1       localhost    localhost.xxx.com    xxx-tele.com
### New Entry
127.0.0.1       localhost  xxx-tele.com
```

Answer (score 1):

### Sendmail: debugging virtusertable

1) Check if sendmailcan access the entry in virtusetable

As root execute:

```
echo /map virtuser info@xxx-tele.com  | sendmail -bt
```

2) Check if sendmail conducts virtusertable lookups for the email.
As root execute:

```
echo '3,0 info@xxx-tele.com' | sendmail -d60.5 -bt
```

-d60.5 traces (all) maps lookups including virtusertable lookups

3) If the domain is rewritten by `host` map lookup **before** virtusertable lookups then check DNS lookups and post `/etc/hots` entries with `xxx-tele.com`

```
echo '3,0 info@xxx-tele.com' | sendmail -d8.20 -bt
```

Comment: The answer for 1.) is `ADDRESS TEST MODE (ruleset 3 NOT automatically invoked) Enter <ruleset> <address> > map_lookup: virtuser (info@xxx-tele.com) returns myuser@tele.com (0) `

Comment: The answer for second command is:
`ADDRESS TEST MODE (ruleset 3 NOT automatically invoked)
Enter <ruleset> <address>
> canonify input: info @ xxx-tele.com
Canonify2 input: info < @ xxx-tele.com >
map_lookup(host, xxx-tele.com, %0=xxx-tele.com) => localhost.xxx.com. (0)
Canonify2 returns: info < @ localhost.xxx.com . >
canonify returns: info < @ localhost.xxx.com . >
parse input: info < @ localhost.xxx.com . >
Parse0 input: info < @ localhost.xxx. com . >
map_lookup(dequote, info, %0=info) => NOT FOUND (0)
Parse0 returns: info < @ localhost.xxx.com . >`

Comment: rest of trace:
`Parse1 input: info < @ localhost. xxx.com . >
map_lookup(virtuser, info@localhost.xxx.com, %0=info@localhost.xxx.com, %1=info) => NOT FOUND (0)
map_lookup(virtuser, @localhost.xxx.com, %0=@localhost.xxx.com, %1=info) => NOT FOUND (0)
Parse1 returns: $# local $: info
parse returns: $# local $: info`

Comment: I have extended the answer. [I should include extra info provided to your question later today]

Comment: Thanks so far, I edited my comment with new information.